# How to call IKImageBrowser cellWasDoubleClickedAtIndex by pressing double keys?

Tags: cocoa, keyboard-events, nsviewcontroller, ikimagebrowserview

I had used IKImageBrowserView to show image gallery.

Currently opening next view on click on image,

I am using double click of left mouse key to call `cellWasDoubleClickedAtIndex` this method.

```
-(void)imageBrowser:(IKImageBrowserView *)aBrowser cellWasDoubleClickedAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    myImageObject *goodThing = [images objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

Now i want to open next view by (Command+Enter) keys on selected image in `IKImageBrowserView`.

Answer (score 0):

//Keep a hidden button with key equivalent as cmd+enter

```
 -(IBAction)nextImageAction:(id)sender
    {
        NSIndexSet *indexSet = [imageBrowser selectionIndexes];
        myImageObject *goodThing = [images objectAtIndex:indexSet.firstIndex+1];
    }
```

Comment: Your answer gives me idea about to take selected object from IKImageBrowser. But what about Command+Enter key detect. Should Command+Enter work for any button !! How to add NSControl in IKImageBrowserCell ?

Comment: Keep a hidden button with key equivalent as cmd+enter. From that IBAction method, you can identify the selected cell